# C# get set javascript equivalent

Tags: javascript, class

is there an equivalent in javascript to the following C# code

```
public class Class
{
    public string str
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I am trying to do something like this

```
    var list = function () {
        this.settings = {
            id: 1
        };
        this.id = //something
    }
    var List = new list();
    alert(List.id); //alerts 1
    List.id = 5; // should set this.settings.id = 5
    alert(List.settings.id); // alerts 5
```

---

Although this answer is good for the c# class, I still cant reference the id as follows

```
    var list = function() {
        this.settings = {
            _id: 0, 
            get id() { return this._id; }, 
            set id(x) { this._id = x; }
        };
        this.id = this.settings.id;
    }

    var List = new list();


    document.write(List.id + "<br />");
    List.id += 10;
    document.write(List.settings.id + "<br />");
```

which is probably because this.settings.id only passes the value back to this.id and not the actual object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var o = {
    _p: 5,
    get p() { return this._p; },
    set p(x) { this._p = x; }
};
```

[Example usage - jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/hcyzd/)

[Defining Getters and Setters - developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters)

Comment: Awesome! the smaller the better.  Doesnt work below IE9 but just tested in Opera, FF and Safari and works a treat.. mucho gracious :)

Answer (score 2):

This wiki article explains Object.defineProperties in detail
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)#JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [John Resig has a great writeup on it](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/), the basic idea is:

```
function Field(val){
    var value = val;

    this.__defineGetter__("value", function(){
        return value;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__("value", function(val){
        value = val;
    });
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/mu6jf/

Comment: The __defineGetter__ and __defineSetter__ are out of fashion now.  Try [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for a cross-browser solution.  Works in IE9 too!

Comment: @ChrisNielsen My wife tells me everything I wear is out of fashion now too. If you want to throw down an answer for that I'll vote you up.